# Why heroku detects my sinatra app as rails and fails?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

```
# Gemfile:
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'octokit'

# app.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'cgi'
require 'octokit'
require 'figaro'

class Application < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    'Hi'
  end
end

# config.ru
require './app'
$stdout.sync = true
run Application
```

When push:
`-----> Ruby/Rails app detected`

However, if I remove `figaro` gem and repush it works fine.

Comment: Write a more precise `Procfile` https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: Figaro looks useful, I didn't know about it. I've written a homegrown version that does pretty much the same thing. If you like using it then forking it and creating a Sinatra version would not only scratch you itch, but several other people's too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered it yourself:
figaro depend on Rails (see the gemspec: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/blob/master/figaro.gemspec). Heroku detect rails application [by looking if their Gemfile.lock](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rails-3-x-applications) contains the Railties gem, which is a dependency of rails.

So: yourapp -> figaro -> rails -> railties.

Hence the identification of your gem as a Rails App. Why are you using Figaro if not to help configure a Rails application anyway?